# Non "Html 5" prevalence?

Tags: html

We are building a small site for a client and while we spoke, the question of html standard popped up and we told him we will do it in HTML5. His question was "what about those who do not support html 5" since he wants to reach the widest possible audience some of whom are in the tech-unsavvy or elderly group?

I've been so deep into html5 for a while that this never crossed my mind, if we use exclusively html5 who exactly is now being left behind and how much of a market share do they represent? I tried googling this, but I can't find any objective material on that topic. I would very much like to avoid falling back on pre-html5 if we are just talking about a few percent of ludites holding out.

Comment: HTML5 is backwards compatible anyway, for the most part.

Comment: For start, <nav> is not and we use it a lot.

Comment: `nav { display: block; }` boom – <nav> support. It doesn't make sense to talk about "HTML5 support" because each browser and browser version supports (or doesn't support) individual features, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on the functionality of HTML 5 you intend to use.

Check out this website: [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com)

Then based on the functionality you intend to use check what browsers support it, then if you need to use that feature and you can only use say IE 11 and above, but all other browsers support it then you check the browser share for IE 10 and below at: https://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx

Unfortunately there's no easy answer to the amount of people unable to use your website depending on if you use 'HTML 5' it depends entirely on the feature set, your potential users locations and browser they use.

If you are building a site for a client with an existing website and they use some form of analytics you could use those stats to define the usage levels of browsers and then work from there.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I needed, "can I use" gives a nice breakdown of html5 semantic elements that shows 97% global coverage. We don't use any of the advanced html5 features. They do have some old site, but the logging on it is terrible/nonexistent.

Comment: @mmix if you can see if you can drop google analytics on it for a month while you build the site, then that way if there's lots of IE 8 or below users you can put up alerts or notifications on launch about upgrading browser etc.